# Split column defintions of SQL create table query

Tags: python, sql

I want to split all column definitions of a sql query into seperate strings.

So:

```
 `citizen_group` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `container_group` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`citizen_group`,`container_group`),
  KEY `fk_containergroup_readeraccess` (`container_group`)
```

Into:

```
['`citizen_group` int(10) NOT NULL', '`container_group` int(10) NOT NULL','PRIMARY KEY (`citizen_group`,`container_group`)',' KEY `fk_containergroup_readeraccess` (`container_group`)']
```

First I used `split(',')`. But this gives a problem when the sql has a multicolumn primary key. I cannot expect that each definition is on a new line, so I can't split on newlines.

How can I split these column definitions?

Comment: What you are trying to parse is not a query (a SELECT statement) but DDL (Data Definition Language, so a CREATE TABLE statement), I think you should correct the wording in your question

Comment: I have the complete query, but I'm only interested in the column definitions.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a bit hacky and I'm sure that there's a better solution, but at least it gets the job done.

EDIT: somewhat better code:

```
data = '''\
    `citizen_group` int(10) NOT NULL,
    `container_group` int(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`citizen_group`,`container_group`),
    KEY `fk_containergroup_readeraccess` (`container_group`)'''

data = data.replace('\n', '')
last = 0
result = []
paren = False
for i, j in enumerate(data):
    if j == '(':
        paren = True
    elif j == ')':
        paren = False
    if j == ',':
        if not paren:
            result.append(data[last:i])
            last = i + 1
result.append(data[last:])
result = map(str.strip, result)

print result
```

results in

```
['`citizen_group` int10 NOT NULL', '`container_group` int(10) NOT NULL',
 'PRIMARY KEY (`citizen_group`,`container_group`)',
 'KEY `fk_containergroup_readeraccess` (`container_group`)']
```